# The concatenation of chars to form a string gives different results

Tags: java, string, char, concatenation

Why, when I use the operation below to sum chars, does it return numbers instead of chars? Shouldn't it give the same result?

```
ret += ... ; // returns numbers

ret = ret + ...; // returns chars
```

The code below duplicates the chars:

doubleChar("The") → "TThhee"

```
public String doubleChar(String str) {

    String ret = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        ret = ret + str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i); // it concatenates the letters correctly
        //ret += str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i); // it concatenates numbers
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The result of the following expression

```
ret + str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

is the result of String concatenation. [The Java language specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object
>   that is the concatenation of the two operand strings. The characters
>   of the left-hand operand precede the characters of the right-hand
>   operand in the newly created string.

The result of

```
str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

is the result of the additive operator applied to two numeric types. [The Java language specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2)

> The binary + operator performs addition when applied to two operands
>   of numeric type, producing the sum of the operands.
>   [...]
>   The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the **promoted**
>   type of its operands.

In which case

```
str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

becomes an `int` holding the sum of the two `char` values. That is then concatenated to `ret`.

---

You might also want to know this about the compound assignment expression `+=`

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent
>   to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1`
>   is evaluated only once.

In other words

```
ret += str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

is equivalent to

```
ret = (String) ((ret) + (str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i)));
                      |                ^ integer addition
                      |
                      ^ string concatenation
```

Comment: But he's doing `ret += str.charAt`, where `res` is a string.

Comment: @MxyL In the second expression, the right hand side is evaluated as a whole before the `+` is applied. That result is a `char` that is the sum of the two.

Comment: @MxyL Also, for additive `+`, `The type of an additive expression on numeric operands is the promoted type of its operands.`

Comment: There's one other fine point I see which is that additive operators are left-to-right associative. So `str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i) + ret` will add the chars numerically as well.

Answer (score 2):

**The First Example**

From the semantics, I'd say we're looking at `arithmetic promotion` at work. Note the first example:

```
String + char + char
```

Due to arithmetic promotion, those two `char` values are *promoted* to `String` values, so the types become:

```
String + String + String
```

The `+` is overloaded, to perform concatenation because all operands are of type `String`.

**The Second Example**

In the second example, as with all assignments, we evaluate the right hand side of the `=` operator first, and what do we have?

```
char + char
```

The char is interpreted as its numerical value, because there is no `String` to cause promotion, and we have a numerical addition, which is then appended to the `String`.

**Extra Reading**

Some notes on *arithmetic promotion* can be found [here](http://www.codemiles.com/java/arithmetic-promotion-t3487.html).

Some notes on expression evaluation can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html).

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, you are explicitly adding a String as the first term. That forces the second and third term to also be promoted to String(s). In the second case, you are adding two characters (which are then appended to the String) - it does not promote to a String until the assignment. You could have been explicit, by using [Character.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29) or [String.valueOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%29) like so

```
ret += Character.toString(str.charAt(i)) + String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> 15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators
>
> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

So the `+=` operator has a built-in cast to the destination type.

In contrast, the [clause for simple assignment says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1):

> 15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =
>
> A compile-time error occurs if the type of the right-hand operand cannot be converted to the type of the variable by assignment conversion (§5.2).

Here,

```
 ret = ret + str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

is treated as a string concatination.

And

```
ret += str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

is treated as aditive operation.

Answer (score 0):

ret = ret + str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i); // // it concatenates the letters correctly

This is because ret is string snd it concatenates with the other characters.

ret += str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i); // it concatenates numbers

This is because the compiler first evaluates 'str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i)' which probably results in a number and then concatenates it with ret. So essentially we evaluate the left side and then assign it.

Hope it clears your confusion.