# + operator on String and char values in println() method in Java

Tags: java

I have following code snippet and their output below:

**String**

```
System.out.println("A");            // output A
System.out.println("B");            // output B
System.out.println("A" + "B");      // output AB
```

**char**

```
System.out.println('A');            // output A
System.out.println('B');            // output B
System.out.println('A' + 'B');      // output 131
```

What is the reason that char's output is getting printed as string for single char value where as integer if **+ operator** is used? I do not find this answer in this post [The concatenation of chars to form a string gives different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387948/the-concatenation-of-chars-to-form-a-string-gives-different-results)

Comment: Because the + operator is not overloaded for chars. Only for Strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+char+concatenation+

Comment: @EngineerDollery: My question is why if System.out.println('A'); // A and System.out.println('A' + 'B'); // 131? why not only integer or only char output? This concept is not present in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387948/the-concatenation-of-chars-to-form-a-string-gives-different-results

Comment: @Farooque -- I beg to differ. The explanation in that question is also the explanation to your conundrum. Thanks for the challenge though; it's good to have to think about what one has committed to.

Comment: @EngineerDollery: I am not challenging but just sharing my view, because this is the place where we are learning new things in each step of moments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the reason that char's out is getting printed as string for single char value where as integer if + operator is used?

There's no `+` operator for `char`, so both operands are being promoted to `int` (values 65 and 66 respectively, in the normal way that `char` is converted to `int`), and the result is `int` as well. Whereas in your string example, it's using the string concatenation operator.

Basically, this is normal operator overload resolution, using the `+` operators described in [JLS 15.18](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18).

Comment: Sometimes, Jon, I think people give you upvotes because you're Jon.  :D  Good answer as usual.

Comment: what about if single char?

Comment: @Farooque: What do you mean? "If single char" what?

Comment: if System.out.println('A');  then why output is A itself and not 65?

Comment: @Farooque: Because that's calling `println(char)`. There's no reason for that to promote to `int`...

Comment: @Jon: OK...thanks, I got my answer.....

Answer (score 4):

Because char `A` represent the value 65 and char `B` represents the value 66.

65 + 66 = 131

So the moral of the story is `+` operator is overloaded for Strings and not for chars. You can consult [JLS string concatentation section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Second case adds [unicode](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) codes of the two characters (`A` - `65` and `B` - `66`) and prints the sum. This is because **`char` is considered a numeric type**.