# Order of empty string in string conversion by concatenating empty string

Tags: java, string, string-concatenation, string-conversion

There are several ways to perform a String conversion in Java and some people (including myself) prefers to concatenate an empty string to do the conversion:

**Example:**

```
char ch = 'A';
String str = "" + ch;   //gets character value and append to str
```

However the order of the empty String is always a mystery to me. The following will successfully perform a String conversion:

```
str = ch + "";    
str = ch + "" + ch;
```

but not the following:

```
str = ch + ch + "";    //if (ch + "") gives us "A", shouldn't this be "65A"?
```

**Que:** To be safe, we can always place the empty String infront, but I want to know how Java interprets the concatenation when the (empty) string is placed in other locations (such as in between or at the back).

Comment: I want to close as duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387948/the-concatenation-of-chars-to-form-a-string-gives-different-results) but I'm undecided. Check it out.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The linked question and solutions are of a different issue. They merely mention about adding characters, but I am asking concatenation of empty string and specifically how its position affect the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` operator is left-associative, which means that it is grouped from left-to-right.

```
str = ch + ch + "";
```

This is equivalent to

```
str = (ch + ch) + "";
 // = ('A' + 'A') + "";
 // = 130 + "";
 // = "130";
```

not

```
str = ch + (ch + "");
 // = 'A' + ('A' + "");
 // = 'A' + "A";
 // = "AA";
```

`char + String` and `String + char` both result in a `String`. But `char + char` returns an `int`. Do you see now why a second `+ ch` doesn't work?

Comment: Short and sweet. That explains everything now, including why placing `""` in front converts the entire line of code to String because every subsequent characters will be added the the converted-string before them. +1 and will accept when time lock is over.